# JavaScript Variable Updating

Tags: javascript, variables, three.js

I noticed that in ThreeJs you:

```
    var a = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    scene.add(a);
    a.position.z += 23.5;
```

You pass the objects cube into scene with all of its verticies etc. but then when you edit it's variables `scene` knows the new coordinates. How is this possible without passing `a` back into `scene`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because you passed object `a` to `scene.add` method "by reference", so that all future changes of `a` are "known" by `scene` object.

To demonstrate this behaviour you can try the following code in your js console:

```
var a = {foo: 'bar'}, scene = {
    add: function(obj) {this.obj = obj},
    print: function() { console.log(this.obj.foo);}
});
scene.add(a);
scene.print(); // outputs bar
a.foo = 'baz';
scene.print(); // outputs baz
```